# Product of two polynomials always preserves the two polynomials roots

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I'm aware of this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/979052/roots-of-product-of-two-polynomials-is-the-union-of-the-roots-of-each-polynomial#:%7E:text=1-,Roots%20of%20product%20of%20two%20polynomials%20is%20the,the%20roots%20of%20each%20polynomial&text=When%20you%20completely%20factor%20r,Q(x)%20or%20both.) but it does not completely answer my question.

---

Hypothesis:  $\mathbb{F}$ is a finite field, and polynomials $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ are defined in $\mathbb{F}[x]$.

I'm looking for a theorem (and proof) which states that:

Polynomial $C(x)=A(x)B(x)$ **always** preserves roots of both  $A$ and $B$.

---

Edit: the polynomials are non-zero.

Comment: Let $x_0$ be a root of $A$, what can you say about $C\left(x_0\right)$ ?

Comment: Mh $0\cdot B(x)=A(x)\cdot 0=0$, maybe ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust thanks for the comment, I've slightly edited my answer to clarify I mean non-zero polynomials.

Comment: If $a$ is a root of $A,$ $C(a)=A(a)B(a) = 0 \cdot B(a).$ Similarly if $b$ is a root of $B$.

Comment: just to double-check--I admit it may seem peculiar. Let ''a'' be a root of A. why cannot we set B(x) as $\frac{B'}{x-a}$?

Comment: @Aresearcher: Mh, I guess you misunderstood my comment. I never meant zero polynomials.

Comment: Can you prove this for polynomials over $\mathbb{R}$?  The proof is the same over any field.

Comment: Not only it preserves the roots, but in any integral domain (in particular in a field), $C(\xi)=0\iff A'\xi)=0\: \text{ OR }\:B(\xi)=0$.

Comment: is that correct that we do not have a multiplicative inverse of a polynomial in $\mathbb{F}[x]$?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $A(\alpha)=0$, then $C(\alpha)=A(\alpha)B(\alpha)=0$. So a root of $A$ is a root of $C$. Likewise for roots of $B$. This applies quite generally.

In any context where there are no (non-trivial) divisors of zero, suppose that $C(x)=A(x)B(x)$ and that $C(\alpha)=0$. Then $A(\alpha)B(\alpha)=0$, and since there are no non-trivial divisors of zero we must have $A(\alpha)=0$ or $B(\alpha)=0$. This applies in the case of a finite field.

There is a little more work to show that multiplicities are respected (this requires counting and hence some form of induction on degree is indicated).

Comment: For multiplicities this is not true: $A$ and $B$ might have a common root.

Comment: @Bernard If $A$ and $B$ have a common root, then $C$ has a double root - I am not sure quite what you think is wrong.

Comment: @Aresearcher indeed. If you have non-zero elements $p$ and $q$ with $pq=0$ you can run into problems. For example, modulo $6$, so in $\mathbb Z_6[x]$ - the ring of polynomials with integer coefficients modulo $6$, $(2x-2)\cdot 3x=0$

Comment: thanks very much! is it correct that we do not have a multiplicative inverse of a polynomial in []?

Comment: @MarkBennet: I would rather say that *multiplicities are added*.